# How to use CircleCI's ecs orbs to do actual ticketing of depends_on

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, circleci

I am currently deploying with CircleCI using ECS orbs.

Here are the contents of config.yaml.

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@8.2.1
  aws-ecs: circleci/aws-ecs@3.2.0


jobs:
  dev-ecr-push-go-image:
    executor: aws-ecr/default
    steps:


workflows:
  ci_workflow:
    jobs:
    - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　name: dev-ecr-push-go-image
        registry-id: DEV_AWS_ECR_REGISTRY_ID
        aws-access-key-id: DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        aws-secret-access-key: DEV_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        public-registry: false
        push-image: true
        dockerfile: ./docker/deploy/go/Dockerfile
        repo: 'development/app'
        tag: '${CIRCLE_SHA1}'

    - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
        name: dev-ecr-push-nginx-image
        registry-id: DEV_AWS_ECR_REGISTRY_ID
        aws-access-key-id: DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        aws-secret-access-key: DEV_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        public-registry: false
        push-image: true
        dockerfile: ./docker/deploy/nginx/Dockerfile
        repo: 'development/nginx'
        tag: '${CIRCLE_SHA1}'
    - aws-ecs/deploy-service-update:
        name: dev-ecs-deploy
        aws-access-key-id: DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        aws-secret-access-key: DEV_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        cluster: 'development'
        container-image-name-updates: 'container=nginx,tag=${CIRCLE_SHA1},container=app,tag=${CIRCLE_SHA1}'
        family: 'development'
        service-name: 'development'
        requires:
        - dev-ecr-push-go-image
        - dev-ecr-push-nginx-image
```

When I create a task, I want the nginx container to be started after the go container is started.
This can be done easily with docker-compose, and I have confirmed that it can also be done with task definitions on the ECS side.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html

But what is the best way to achieve dependsOn with CircleCI?
I checked the orbs documentation but could not find a solution.
https://circleci.com/developer/ja/orbs/orb/circleci/aws-ecs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a configuration error in my task_definition.json.
I forgot to set the order of containers to be launched with "links".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).